# Error in storing values in SQL database table

Tags: sql-server, sqldatatypes

In my table, there is a column called `zipcode` whose datatype is `int`. And when I am storing a zipcode which starts with 0 (for eg. `08872`), it is getting stored as `8872`.

Can anybody explain me why is it happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `INT` value is numeric - and numerically, `08872` and `8872` are identical - both represent the value `8872`.

SQL Server will **not** store leading zeroes for numerical values. That's just the way it is.

Either store this as `CHAR(5)` instead, or handle the formatting (adding leading zeroes to your zip codes) on the frontend when you need to display it.

Comment: I tried that also, i.e. set the datatype as 'VARCHAR(MAX)'. But when i am using 'resultset.getString(zipcode)' the problem persists. It still returns the value is '8872'.

Comment: @animeshporwal: if you only ever intend to store 5 characters - make it a `CHAR(5)` - **definitely NOT** a `VARCHAR(MAX)` !!